# Laravel Eloquent cache query conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my UserController@getIndex, it output some users and all user count.

```
$name = Input::get('name');
$page = Input::get('page');
$limit = Input::get('limit');
$users = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->skip($limit*$page)->take($limit)
        ->get();

return array(
    'rows'=>$users->toArray(),
    'results'=>User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->count(),
);
```

Is there any way I can reuse the 'where()' part so I don't have to repeat my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) not to repeat yourself:

```
//app/models/User.php
public function scopeFilterName($query, $name) {
    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%');
}

///////////////////////////

//in the controller
$name = Input::get('name');
$page = Input::get('page');
$limit = Input::get('limit');
$users = User::filterName($name)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->skip($limit*$page)->take($limit)
        ->get();

return array(
    'rows'=>$users->toArray(),
    'results'=>User::filterName($name)->count(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, scope is a good way to do this. But I think scope should be used in some more "common" way like "scopeFemale" or "scopeOld".
This Controller is respond to admin panel, for other resources like "order", the filters is more complicated, it's just for admin grid filter, used only in this action, so is there any convenience way?

Comment: Scopes are the recommended and in my opinion the easiest way to achieve this approach. What I can think of is using the boot() method in model events and setting a conditional where clause there, but I've not tried, and even it'd succeed it'd sure be more complicated. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events

Answer (score 1):

Not very convenient way, but it will give you idea of how Builder works:

```
$query = User::where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%");
$anotherQuery = clone $query;

$query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')   // you can use latest() method for this btw
   ->skip( 5 )  // sets OFFSET 5
   ->take( 10 )  // sets LIMIT 10
   ->get();
```

Now, those clauses remain on the builder, so this will return null:

```
$query->count();
```

because of that `OFFSET 5`

So you can use:

```
$anotherQuery->count();
```

or:

```
$query->skip(0)->take(9999);
```

or even less convenient:

```
$query->getQuery()  // get the base Query Builder object
    ->limit = null;
$query->getQuery()->offset = null;
```

---

And just a note - I don't agree that `scope` doesn't fit here, I would use it in fact.

Comment: This is very close to what I want...If I use scope for this scenario, it means for most of models, there will be a function scopeFilter(diffrentArgs)?

Comment: Scope works only for the model it's defined in. It's just a handy DRY feature for common tasks. `filterName($name)`, `male()`, `recentlyUpdated()` etc. You can define it however suits you, it's just a set of query constraints.